# Git Rebase On Two Branches Has Same Conflicts Every Time

Tags: git, github

I have three main branches I typically use. We can call them master, staging, and development. A couple weeks ago, I think I or someone on my team rebased or merged something in a strange way such that now whenever we commit changes to development and then try to rebase them to staging, we get a conflict on a single file. HEAD is always correct when this happens. When I manually go in and pick this and try to git `git rebase --continue`, I get:

> No changes - did you forget to use 'git add'? If there is nothing left
>   to stage, chances are that something else already introduced the same
>   changes; you might want to skip this patch.

So, I can get away with running `git rebase --skip` to get rid of this problem for now, just going with HEAD, and get to have my new changes in the staging branch. Same thing happens when I try to then rebase staging to master. This would be fine, except this exact same thing happens *every time I do rebasing between these branches now,* and the problem is always *that old exact same file*.

Upon inspection, it looks like development and staging both have recent commits in the wrong chronological order for some reason. How do I fix this? The problem seems to have happened late November, and all branches share the exact same commits since then. Just ordering the commits in development and staging since late november in the same order as master (or just chronological order) would be fine for me. The main thing is I just want to be able to rebase normally again.

Comment: You can reorder commits with interactive rebasing (`git rebase -i`). Your problem also makes me wonder if there's some whitespace conflict, and you have your whitespace handling set up in a way that ignores it, but then conflicts with it again each time.

Comment: @GaryFixler git rebase - i would reorder commits that have already been push to remote and screw up everyone else working on these branches.

Comment: True, but if you want to actually reorder those commits, that's what you would have to do. You might get away with doing a `git revert` on the earlier one to undo it in a new commit, then commit it again. This doesn't really sound like the problem, though.

Comment: This is the reason I'm not a big fan of using rebase on long-lived branches. It's too big of a lie. It's great for daily work, though, fixing up small things from the last few hours, or minutes, or as a final cleanup before I push a handful of commits from today's efforts. When I was first learning git a year ago, I kept rebasing a branch. It got into the 500-600 commit range, and rebasing was getting slower and slower. Now I prefer occasional reintegration merges. It's more true to the history. Also, while refactorings update through rebases, comments about them don't, and can become lies.

Answer (score 0):

I wound up dealing with this by rebasing the other two branches on master:

```
git checkout some_branch
git rebase master
```

to get commits correctly ordered (nothing else changed, so reordering was all that happened) and then force pushed to origin. I then had my teammates reset those branches to origin:

```
git fetch --all
git reset --hard origin/some_branch
```

Not the most elegant solution, but very quick in our case, and since I haven't gotten any other answers, I'll provide this for anyone facing the same problem.